# How to intract with Burrow using JSONRPC

Tags: hyperledger, json-rpc

I am using Burrow for creating account, get transaction details and to get balance. i want to try this using JSON RPC using Node js. Could any one can explain me how i can use http server or request model of node js to interact with burrow client.